# Vectorise assignment of R data.table cells with column differing by row

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I'm having a problem thinking about how to efficiently assign individual cells of a data.table by reference. Each column (aside from id) is indicative of that subjects state on a particular day.

For the sake of illustration, the column to be toggled of each row is stored in a separate list or vector. The following for loop does the job, but the actual data are very large (hence also assigning by reference), and a more native solution would be ideal.

```
dt = data.table(id = letters[1:5],
                `1`=0,`2`=0,`3`=0)

d = c(3,2,1,2,3)

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  print(d[i])
  dt[i,1+d[i] := 1]
}

print(dt)
# id 1 2 3
# 1:  a 0 0 1
# 2:  b 0 1 0
# 3:  c 1 0 0
# 4:  d 0 1 0
# 5:  e 0 0 1
```

Everything I try using .SD or .I fails, perhaps someone could point me in the right direction?

e.g.

```
dt[,d[.I] := 1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `set` or `:=` in a for-loop for columns instead of rows:

```
for(i in seq_along(dt)[-1]){
    set(dt, NULL, i, 0 + (d == i - 1))
}
dt
#    id 1 2 3
# 1:  a 0 0 1
# 2:  b 0 1 0
# 3:  c 1 0 0
# 4:  d 0 1 0
# 5:  e 0 0 1
```

Comment: noting that `set` is also an `update by reference` operator in `data.table`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to start with a `data.table` of the `id`s and the vector of states, then reshape

```
dt <- data.table(id = letters[1:5], state = d)
#    id state
# 1:  a     3
# 2:  b     2
# 3:  c     1
# 4:  d     2
# 5:  e     3

dcast(dt, id ~ state, fun.aggregate = length)

#    id 1 2 3
# 1:  a 0 0 1
# 2:  b 0 1 0
# 3:  c 1 0 0
# 4:  d 0 1 0
# 5:  e 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` method would be to use `row/column` index

```
setDF(dt)
dt[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(dt)), d)] <- 1
dt
#  id 1 2 3
#1  a 0 0 1
#2  b 0 1 0
#3  c 1 0 0
#4  d 0 1 0
#5  e 0 0 1
```